# How to check if a certain method has been called?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a *pop* effect for this game that I am creating, and I have run into a problem when trying to check if the method has been called.

I have already took a stab at what I think should work the only problem is the Boolean method, and I have created always returns true?

Here is the code for the class that I think is **causing** the problem:

```
public class Handler {
    LinkedList<GameObject> object = new LinkedList<GameObject>();
    public static boolean blank = false;
    public void tick(){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size();i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.tick();
        }

    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        for(int i = 0; i < object.size();i++){
            GameObject tempObject = object.get(i);

            tempObject.render(g);
        }

    }

    public void addObject(GameObject object){
        this.object.add(object);
    }

    public void removeObject(GameObject object){
        blank = true;
        this.object.remove(object);
    }
    public static boolean hasObjectRemoved(){
        if(blank = true){
            blank = false;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

As you can see, I am trying to check whether or not the `removeObject` method has been called or not.

Comment: Look into the Observer pattern or using an interceptor.

Comment: Or you may use **System.out.println("Has been called");** inside the method

Comment: Why is half this class static and half isn't?

Comment: Observer pattern? and interceptor? Im not sure what those are

Comment: @devin The internet has loads of explanations for both.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Because he may have multiple instances of `Handler`?

Comment: `if(blank = true)` should be `if (blank == true)`, otherwise it's making an assignment, and always returning true. But I agree with David's post, you should be looking into a more asynchronous pattern for handling this rather than depending on mutable (and non-threadsafe) state. If you must use a boolean, you could look into `AtomicBoolean` or double-checked locking.

Comment: it does not matter whether the methods and or variables are static or not if they are. The ones that aren't matter

Comment: where can i learn more about AtomicBoolean and asynchronous patterns. I know java, but that looks like a foreign language to me

Comment: `AtomicBoolean` is part of java.util.concurrent. As far as asynchronous patterns, that's a much larger question. "Java Concurrency in Practice" might be a good place to start.

Comment: I'd be worried about relying on `static`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(blank = true)
```

Should be

```
if(blank == true)
```

= is assigning the value of true to the variable blank

== will ask the question is blank equal to true

Answer (score 1):

put this in your method to test

```
System.out.println("removeObject method");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `blank = true`, you are assigning a value rather than comparing the value.

While you can replace it with `blank == true`, which will work fine, it's unnecessary to use the `==` operator at all. Instead, use `if (blank)` to check if it is true, and `if (!blank)` to check if it is false.